# Use "Site pages" web part as a code snippet

Tags: site, web, pages, snippet

The site I am running has several sub sites with individual themes for colours etc. Each subsite has a section at the top for the in site links, because the main navigation is consistent on every level of the site. I have managed to create this on the page directly using the "site pages" webpart put into the page - it acts exactly as I'd like it to.

However having it available on the page means the client might accidentally delete it. What I'd like to do is insert it as a secondary menu in the master page for that subsite, and maintain the function of the site pages webpart (auto updating etc).

However I can't find a code snippet that matches the "site pages" web part. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you fear customer may delete content accidently,you should really think about disaster recovery scenarios like Item-Level Backup/Restore using PS(export-web) or Data Protection Manager(DPM).